# JavaScript API Response - if clause for 'null' response

Tags: javascript, api, rest, cypress

Can someone assist, please, in following case:

Have a **.json** response with **person's data** where, that person can or can not be assigned to some **project**.

Below is part of response where person is not assigned to project:

```
"contactPerson": {
      "id": "someUUID",
      "firstName": "string",
      "lastName": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "title": "string"
    },
    "project": null
```

Response where person is assigned to a project:

```
"contactPerson": {
      "id": "someUUID",
      "firstName": "string",
      "lastName": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "title": "string"
    },
    "project": {
      "id": "projectUUID",
      "name": "This is a project name ",
      "fullName": "This is a full project name with over 55 chars",
}
```

Tried with simple if clause, but without success.

```
if (typeOf(response.body[i].project.id !== null) {
 //assert elements in project array
} else {
//assert is 'null
}
```

Always got followin error:

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

Does anyone have the idea how to solve it?
Assert if there is assigned project or not.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why are you trying to check `project.id`, when `project` _itself_ is null?

Comment: A simple `if(response.body[i].project)` should probably already be sufficient.

Comment: @CBroe But, in next case project is not null rather it has some data, and my test fails when project has value null

Or, do not have the idea how to skip when project is null

Comment: Because `project` itself is null. `response.body[i].project?.id` should work

Comment: @CBroe It returns error which I add into question body, for simple if - "Cannot read properties ..."

Comment: `project` is not `null` when he gets the response. This is a condition he is trying to check when it's not `!== null`. @Zoran what does the `typeOf` does inside your `if` condition with a missing closing `)` parenthesis, is this typo in this post or is your real code trying to call `typeOf` function?

Comment: @Aleksandar _"project is not null when he gets the response."_ - it _is_ in the first example chunk of data they gave, and it also is according to the error message.

Comment: @Aleksandar  Typo, sorry

Comment: _"It returns error which I add into question body, for simple if"_ - of course it does, because you are trying to access `project.id`, when `project` itself is null. If it is null, you can't read _any_ properties of it, which is what the message is telling you. _Again:_ You need to check that `response.body[i].project` is not null, before you try to proceed and access any properties below it.

Comment: @CBroe nevermind it, I didn't notice the OP was trying to access `.id` out of it, my eyes were focused on the trying-to-be-used-with-a-typo `typeof` operator in a wrong way. But there's already an answer which "*works*" for OP, so everyone's satisified.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, `response.body[i].project.id` will be undefined since `response.body[i].project` is `null`.

It will actually throw an error;

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'id')

As mentioned in comments, simply checking `response.body[i].project` is enough.

Checking with `typeof` on `response.body[i].project`  will actually return `object`.

So either check;

```
if(response.body[i].project)
```

This works since `null` is `falsy` value, and it is equal to doing;

```
if(response.body[i].project == null)
```

To actually check if `null`;

```
if(Object.is(response.body[i].project, null))
```

Or

```
if(response.body[i].project === null)
```

```js
const response = {
  "contactPerson": {
      "id": "someUUID",
      "firstName": "string",
      "lastName": "string",
      "email": "string",
      "title": "string"
    },
    "project": null
};

console.log(response.project); // null

console.log(typeof(response.project)); // object

console.log(response.project == null); // true

console.log(response.project === null); // true

console.log(Object.is(response.project, null)); // true
```

Comment: Second solution works exactly what I been looking for
Thank you very much

Comment: @Zoran maybe accept the answer :-)

Comment: Acepted and thank you, again